# Finding minimum value in sublist containing integers and strings

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to iterate over list of lists and remove the lowest value in each sublist. When I use the min() BIF, it yields a TypeError as I am comparing string and integer values. How do I avoid this comparison and find the min value in the sublist?

```
studentList = [['A', 2, 5, 7], ['B', 6, 2, 9], ['C', 5, 3, 9]]
for student in studentList:
    student.remove(min(student))
print(studentList)
```

Comment: how do you define the minimum value if there are both strings and numbers? Are the strings in the list indicating labels? If that is the case you may want to consider using a `dict`

Comment: What do you think is the minimum value? Do you only want to exclude the first element (i.e. `min(student[1:])`)?

Comment: Is 'A' greater or less than 2?

Comment: for the first sublist, lets say the students name is abbreviated to 'A', and the subsequent integers are marks, I want to remove the lowest mark (integer). So for the first sublist, I want to remove 2.

Answer (score 0):

> lets say the students name is abbreviated to 'A', and the subsequent
>   integers are marks, I want to remove the lowest mark (integer)

In your case, you should skip the first item in each sublist, then - get the minimum from remaining sequence:

```
studentList = [['A', 2, 5, 7], ['B', 6, 2, 9], ['C', 5, 3, 9]]
for student in studentList:
    student.remove(min(student[1:]))

print(studentList)
```

The output:

```
[['A', 5, 7], ['B', 6, 9], ['C', 5, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first value in the sub list represents a label then your data would make much more sense to store it as a `dict`, this way you don't have to do extra processing to ignore the label when dealing with the numbers:

```
studentList = [['A', 2, 5, 7], ['B', 6, 2, 9], ['C', 5, 3, 9]]
#use the first value in the list as the 'key' and use the rest of the values as the 'value'
studentMarks = {student[0]:student[1:] for student in studentList}

for marks in studentMarks.values():
    marks.remove(min(marks))

>>> studentMarks
{'B': [6, 9], 'C': [5, 9], 'A': [5, 7]}
```

This data structure may be more useful since now `studentMarks['A']` will give you the marks for student `A`, `studentMarks.keys()` will give you a list of all student names and `studentMarks.values()` the list of all marks lists.